# Homeomorphisms between lens spaces and Poincaré conjecture

Tags: algebraic-topology

It is known that $L(p,q)\cong L(p,q')$ if and only if $q\equiv \pm (q')^{\pm 1}\mod p$ where

$$
L(p,q)\cong{\mathbb{S}^3}/\mathord{\sim}
$$
is the quotient space generated by the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-action
$$
\rho(z_1,z_2)=(\zeta z_1,\zeta^q z_2)
$$

where $\zeta$ is a pth root of unity and $p$ and $q$ are coprimes.

Right to left implication can be proven using Reidemeister torsion ([https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Torsion.pdf](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/Torsion.pdf) page 104). However, left to right proof is supposed to be verified easily by the reader. Does someone know how to construct the homeomorphism between $L(p,q)$ and $L(p,q')$ assuming the congruence on $q$ and $q'$?

EXTRA QUESTION:
Does the Poincaré conjecture imply that every closed compact orientable 3-manifold with $\pi_1(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ is a lens space?

Comment: I  think your last question is true. The universal cover is a closed, connected, simply connected 3-manifold, and hence a sphere, so $X$ is a quotient of $S^3$ by some covering space action by $\mathbb Z/p$.

Comment: An answer to your first question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788149/diffeomorphism-of-lens-spaces) (although I admit to not reading it carefully.)

Comment: @AndresMejia how could you be sure that there are no more $\mathbb{Z}_p$-actions on $S^3$ other than the ones that define lens spaces?

Comment: great question. I don’t think I have a good answer off the top of my head. I hope somebody with a better background in low dimensional topology has something to say.

Comment: For your extra question: PC is not enough but it is a special case of Thurston's Geometrization Conjecture (called Spherical Space Form Conjecture), proven by Perelman.

Comment: @AndresMejia Uniqueness of the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-action on $S^3$ follows from linear algebra. If $M$ is a matrix in $O(4)$ such that $M^p = I$, then the minimal polynomial of $M$ divides $x^p - 1$. You can then use some primary decomposition theorem to show that $M$ is always conjugate to some combination of classical $2 \times 2$ rotation matrices plus reflections. (This should, in fact, be true for higher-dimensional spheres as well.)

Answer (score 2):

For two roots of unity $\lambda,\mu$ define $\rho_{\lambda,\mu}: (z,w)\mapsto (\lambda z, \mu w)$. Then $\rho_{\lambda,\mu}$ and $\rho_{\lambda,\bar\mu}$ are conjugate via the orthogonal map
$$
(z,w)\mapsto (z, \bar{w}). 
$$
This shows that $L(p,q)$ is homeomorphic to $L(p,-q)$.

Next, if $q$ is coprime to the orders of $\lambda,\mu$ then the subgroup generated by $\rho_{\lambda,\mu}$ is the same as the one generated by $(\rho_{\lambda,\mu})^q$.

Lastly, assuming that $p$ is coprime to $q$, $q'$,
$qq'\equiv 1$  mod $p$, and
$$
\lambda=\exp(i 2\pi/p), \mu= \exp(i 2\pi q/p), 
\mu'= \exp(i 2\pi q'/p), 
$$
then
$$
\lambda^{q'}= \exp(i 2\pi q'/p), 
$$
$$
\mu^{q'}= \exp(i 2\pi /p).  
$$
In other words, the subgroup generated by $\rho_{\lambda,\mu}$ is the same as generated by
$\rho_{\mu',\lambda}$. However, $\rho_{\mu',\lambda}$ is
conjugate in $U(2)$ to $\rho_{\lambda,\mu'}$ via
$$
(z,w)\mapsto (w,z). 
$$
This proves that $L(p,q)$ is homeomorphic to $L(p,q')$.

Lastly, for your extra question, PC is not enough, you need [SSFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_space_form_conjecture#:%7E:text=In%20geometric%20topology%2C%20the%20spherical,isometries%20of%20the%203%2Dsphere.). The later was proven by Perelman in the same paper(s) where he proves the Poincare Conjecture.